# PHP & MySQL preview button question

Tags: php, mysql

How would you go about creating a preview button for a form using PHP & MySQL.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What do you want to preview? The form input? Do you need to show and update the preview as the user is typing, a la Stack Overflow, or do you want the user to submit the form before displaying, etc.

Comment: I want the user to be able to preview the form before they submit the form to the database.

Comment: If you can provide the Form code, U can get more comprehensive answer

Comment: You can also concat my answer with the answer given by Col. Sharpenal, That will will be perfect thing you want..

Answer (score 3):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function formpreview(form) {
form.target='_blank';
form.action='preview.php';
form.submit();
}
//-->
</script> 
<input type="button" value="preview" onclick='formpreview(this.form)'>
```

then use `$_POST` array values in the `preview.php` to populate the template

Answer (score 1):

When a form is submitted to a PHP script, the information from that form is automatically made available to the script. There are many ways to access this information. The norm is to insert it directly into a database.

If I am understanding you correctly, then you should be able to get user input data directly via a GET or POST method.

Have a read through the [PHP Documentation for Variables from External Sources](http://au.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Answer (score 1):

get user input data directly via a GET or POST method.

and then create 2 "if" loop like wise

```
if($_POST['preview'])// after completing the fields preview is clicked. 
{
//display the preview.... and provide a submit button in this preview

}
```

> NOTE: the submit should also b
>   available 
>       in form where INPUT is given , i.e , there should be three buttons,
>   Submit,
>        Preview and Reset..

```
 if($_POST['submit'])
{
//Finally,submit the values into the database..
//if needed redirect to the page of final display of form values...
}
```